# how to include more columns with group by clause?

Tags: sql, group-by

suppose I have a flight table which has year, month, day, origin(airport code), dest(airport code), flight, air_time(flight duration), and distance(between airports). I need to calculate for each given day the max flight speed and include also in the results the corresponding airports and flight number. I am using the code below but getting error message (AnalysisException: select list expression not produced by aggregation output (missing from GROUP BY clause?): origin ). What should I do?

```
select year, month, day, origin, dest, flight,
       round(max(distance/nullif(air_time,0)*60),2) as max_speed
from flights
group by year, month, day;
```

edit: here is one way to get airport and flight info included:

```
select b.* from
(
  select *, max(speed) over (partition by year, month, day) as max_speed
  from
  (
    select *, round((distance/nullif(air_time,0)*60),2) as speed
    from flights
  ) as a
) as b
where b.speed = b.max_speed;
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Including the error message would also help

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, _except_ those who are arguments to set functions.